# How to config Emacs to fit screen size on startup?

Tags: emacs, elisp

My `Emacs` often extends outside the **visible range** of a screen on startup, e.g. on a virtual machine, as shown below. This becomes a problem because the status line is **invisible** (and it's tedious to ask users to resize their Emacs every time).

Is there a way to config Emacs (e.g. in `init.el`) to automatically detect screen size and fit the Emacs window inside the visible view port?

[image]

Comment: You may find this useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151449/can-i-detect-the-display-size-resolution-in-emacs

Comment: @hkdtam Thanks. Indeed this is very helpful.

Comment: How about?:  `M-x toggle-frame-maximized` or simply put `(toggle-frame-maximized)` at the bottom of `init.el`/`.emacs`.  For my personal setup, I use `(x-server-version)` and `(display-pixel-width)` and `(display-pixel-height)` to programmatically identify the OS and screen size.  In my case, various versions of Windows (some native, some virtual machine, XP, 7) and OSX, and then I set the frame precisely using `default-frame-alist` and predetermined pixel width/height and a developer build of Emacs that supports all of the bug fixes and features relating to my previous feature request 21415.